# Music player application

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame, mixer

I am building a simple music player using python. But on clicking the Play Button I am not able to play the song but on clicking Stop the message: Process finished with exit code 0 is displayed on the terminal

```
from tkinter import *
from pygame import mixer

window = Tk()

mixer.init()

window.geometry('300x300')  # set dimension of the window
window.title('Music Player')  # title of the window

textLabel = Label(window, text="Play Button")
textLabel.pack()

def play_song():
    mixer.music.load('Particula.mp3')
    mixer.music.play()
def stop_song():
    mixer.music.stop()

play_photo = PhotoImage(file='play.png')
playButton = Button(window, image=play_photo, command=play_song)
playButton.pack()
stop_photo = PhotoImage(file='stop.png')
stopButton = Button(window, image=stop_photo, command=stop_song)
stopButton.pack()
window.mainloop()  # responsible for all kind of updation on the window
```

[image: i have the music in the project directory]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: On clicking the play button, the song is not getting played.

Comment: Ok, can you verify that the song is being loaded?

Comment: Yeah, I added print statements and the statements were executed.

Comment: `tkinter` and `pygame` may not play (no pun intended) well together.

Comment: I run the same code without problems. Mp3 was played

Answer (score 0):

I have imported your code and it works fine on my laptop. I am able to play as well as stop the song without any error.